# find a number for minimum sum of absolute difference in an array

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

for example, `array a[]= {1,1,10}`, we need to find 'x' such that `|x-1|+|x-1|+|x-10|` is minimum. 
here, x is 1.

Could it be solved in greedy approach, like taking average or something else?

Note: taking average doesn't work, **why**?

I can only come up with `O(nlogn)` solution (binary search), is there any other approach like dp?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: binary search is an `0(logn)` algorithm

Comment: of course it is `O(logn)`, and I am doing binary search n times, so it is `O(nlogn)`. By the way, I thought more about that solution and it can be reduced to O(n) without bin search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very simple question (don't feel offended: at least, the answer is simple if you know it):

If you have an odd number of items, then the one in the middle will be your optimum.

If you have an even number, any number between the central two will be equally optimal.

So no numerical calculation is needed, only sorting :)

---

Explanation: to move your resulting number will change each of the `abs(x-x1)` by the same amount, but with different signs: some increasing and some decreasing.

From the point in the center (in the odd case) there will be one more increasing `abs` when moving in either direction; while when moving between the two central points (in the even case) there will be equally many `abs` of each sign.

Comment: This is also called the **median**.

Comment: I didn't know it, Thanks! It is easy to understand when I think with divide and conquer method. Same way it is easy to see why average isn't an answer.