# Find a number for minimum sum of nth power of absolute difference in an array

Tags: algorithm, math

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973950/find-a-number-for-minimum-sum-of-absolute-difference-in-an-array), but instead if the absolute difference is raised to a power 'c' (which will be given as input) is there an algorithm to find the answer?

For example, given `A = {a1, a2,...., an}` and `c` it should find an `x` such that it minimises `|a1 − x|^c +|a2 − x|^c +··· +|an − x|^c`.

If `c = 1` it's the median of the sorted array and if `c = 2` it's the average of the array, but I can't find connection between median and average which we can extend to any value of `c`.

Comment: As `c` gets larger, the outliers carry more weight. In the extreme, when `c` is very large, you could probably just take the midpoint between the minimum and maximum elements of the array. If I had to guess, when c is 3, 4, 5, I'd average the elements that are more than 1, 2, 3 standard deviations respectively from the mean.

Comment: Note that you might have better luck on https://math.stackexchange.com/. Maybe there actually is a precise mathematical solution.

Comment: When `c` is an even integer, you can ignore the absolute value signs and differentiate, letting you use Newton's method or some other iterative root-finding algorithm. It's not a closed form solution, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `c` is a positive integer.

If it is not an integer, then the fractional powers are hard to calculate.  If it is negative, then as `x` goes to infinity (either way) the result goes to 0, so there is no global minimum.  If it is 0, then `x` does not matter.  So a positive integer is the only thing that makes sense.

Now each term is a convex function.  The sum of convex functions is itself convex.  Convex functions have the following properties.  Suppose that `x < y < z`.  If `f(x) = f(z)` then the global minimum is between them.  If `f(x) = f(y) = f(z)`, that's a straight line segment.  And finally, if `f(y) < min(f(x), f(z))` then the global minimum is between `x` and `z`.

This is sufficient for a variation on binary search.

```
while z - x > some tolerance:
    if z-y > y-x:
        y1 = (y + z) / 2
        if f(y1) < f(y):
            (x, y, z) = (y, y1, z)
        elif f(y1) = f(y):
            (x, y, z) = (y1, (2*y1 + y)/3, y)
        else:
            (x, y, z) = (y1, y, z)
    else:
        y1 = (x + y) / 2
        if f(y1) < f(y):
            (x, y, z) = (x, y1, y)
        elif f(y1) = f(y):
            (x, y, z) = (y1, (2*y1 + y)/3, y)
        else:
            (x, y, z) = (y1, y, z)
```

As this runs, each iteration reduces the size of the interval to at most 3/4 of what it previously was.  And therefore you will narrow in on the answer.

If you special case `c = 1`, you can do even better.  The second derivative will be defined everywhere and be a non-decreasing function.  This allows you to do a binary search, but guess where in the interval the minimum is expected to be.  If you land close, you know which way you're wrong, and can put a much tighter bound on it.

Comment: @kcsquared OOPS, I got the terms backwards.  I hate that.  Thanks for catching it.